# How to detect up/down scroll for a Column with vertical scroll?

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, vertical-scrolling

I have a column which has many items; based on the scroll, I want to show/hide the Floating action button, in case the scroll is down, hide it and in case the scroll is up, show it.

My code is working partially, but **the scrolling is buggy**. Below is the code. Need help.

```
 Column(
      Modifier
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.background_color))
        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .scrollable(
          orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
          state = rememberScrollableState {
            offset.value = it

              coroutineScope.launch {
                scrollState.scrollBy(-it)
              }

            it
          },
        )
    ) { // 10-20 items }
```

Based on the offset value (whether positive/negative), I am maintaining the visibility of FAB.

Comment: Where is the FloatingActionButton?

Comment: Its in Scaffold, the Column is under Scaffold's content

Comment: Is lazyColumn an option instead of a scrollable Column?

Comment: Lazy column has issues with loading images from network, last i tried, that's why i am working with Column as of now. Anyway, I just need to know, how to detect the up/down scroll ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `nestedScroll` modifier.

Something like:

```
val fabHeight = 72.dp //FabSize+Padding
val fabHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { fabHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
val fabOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

            val delta = available.y
            val newOffset = fabOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
            fabOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-fabHeightPx, 0f)

            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

Since composable supports nested scrolling just apply it to the `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
        Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        //..

        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = -fabOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) },
                onClick = {}
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"")
            }
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                //....your code
            }
        }
 )
```

It can work with a `Column` with `verticalScroll` and also with a `LazyColumn`.

[image]

Comment: The only issue I am facing is that while scrolling to the bottom most item, the scroll automatically jumps up a little.. it only happens when at the bottom most item.

Comment: Is there a way to have "shrink and grow" offset instead of the "slide up and slide down" for floating action button?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Hi, how can I make custom vertical scrollable in backdropScaffold ?